# What is the preferred way of working with dates and JavaScript?

Tags: faunadb

When working with a Faunadb record that contains a date value, I struggled with using that date in JavaScript. Eventually I got it working like so:

```js
project.shipDate = new Date(await client.query(q.Format('%t', project.shipDate)));
```

This seems fine, but I also noticed I could do this:

```js
let test = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(project.created));
console.log(test);
datetest = new Date(test["@date"]);
```

Which seems wonky (grin), but may be quicker as it's not using the Fauna client library. Which should I prefer?

Answer (score 1):

The JS driver has several helper classes that let you cast the javascript Time and Date objects to their FQL counterparts.

Here is an example.

### From Fauna to JS

You can create a new document that contains a date value.

```js
const project = await client.query(
  q.Create(
    q.Collection("projects"),
    { data: { shipDate: q.ToDate(q.Now()) } }
  )
)
```

You can retrieve the date value and use as a javascript `Date` object by using the `value` property

```js
const shipDate = new Date(project.data.shipDate.value)
```

### From JS to Fauna

The date value can be modified however you want, and you can pass it back to FQL using the `values.FaunaDate` class.

```js
const { values } = require('faunadb')

/* ... */

let nextDay = new Date(shipDate.getTime() + 86400000)
const faunaDate = new values.FaunaDate(nextDay)
```

### Full Example

```js
const project = await client.query(
  q.Create(
    q.Collection("projects"),
    { data: { shipDate: q.ToDate(q.Now()) } }
  )
)
console.log(project)

const shipDate = new Date(project.data.shipDate.value)
console.log(shipDate)

let nextDay = new Date(shipDate.getTime() + 86400000)
console.log(nextDay)

const projectRef = project.ref
const projectUpdate = await client.query(
  q.Update(
    projectRef,
    { data: { shipDate: new values.FaunaDate(nextDay) } }
  )
)
console.log(projectUpdate)
```

```sh
{
  ref: Ref(Collection("projects"), "307924674409398337"),
  ts: 1629918703380000,
  data: { shipDate: Date("2021-08-25") }
}
2021-08-25T00:00:00.000Z
2021-08-26T00:00:00.000Z
{
  ref: Ref(Collection("projects"), "307924674409398337"),
  ts: 1629918703470000,
  data: { shipDate: Date("2021-08-26") }
}
```